# pandas sort lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Given a dataframe `a` with 3 columns, `A` , `B` , `C` and 3 rows of numerical values.  How does one sort all the rows with a comp operator using only the product of `A[i]*B[i]`.  It seems that the pandas sort only takes columns and then a sort method.
I would like to use a comparison function like below.

```
f = lambda i,j: a['A'][i]*a['B'][i] < a['A'][j]*a['B'][j]
```

Answer (score 26):

There are at least two ways:

**Method 1**

Say you start with

```
In [175]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, -1], 'C': [1, 1]})
```

You can add a column which is your sort key

```
In [176]: df['sort_val'] = df.A * df.B
```

Finally sort by it and drop it

```
In [190]: df.sort_values('sort_val').drop('sort_val', 1)
Out[190]: 
   A  B  C
1  2 -1  1
0  1  1  1
```

**Method 2**

Use [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and then use `.ix` on the resulting indices:

```
In [197]: import numpy as np

In [198]: df.ix[np.argsort(df.A * df.B).values]
Out[198]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2 -1  1
```

Comment: That put me on the right track.  Thanks.  I found that for subsets iloc is needed.                                                                                               >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 2,3,1],'B': [1, -1,-1,3],'C': [1, 1,3,4]})
>>> df
    A  B  C
0  10  1  1
1   2 -1  1
2   3 -1  3
3   1  3  4
>>> x = df[(df['A']!=1)]
>>> x
    A  B  C
0  10  1  1
1   2 -1  1
2   3 -1  3
>>> x.iloc[np.argsort(x.A *x.C).values]
    A  B  C
1   2 -1  1
2   3 -1  3
0  10  1  1
>>>

Comment: One way to do method one in a single expression, without mutating the original data frame: `df.assign(sortval = df.A * df.B).sort_values('sortval').drop('sortval', 1)`.

Answer (score 15):

Another way, adding it here because this is the first result at Google:

```
df.loc[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]
```

This works well for me and is pretty straightforward. @Ami Tavory's answer gave strange results for me with a categorical index; not sure it's because of that though.

Comment: super elegant! I'd also mention `df.**iloc**[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]` if your index if position-based (vs label-based)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding on @srs **super elegant** answer an **`iloc`** option with some time comparisons with `loc` and the naive solution.

(iloc is preferred for when your your index is position-based (vs label-based for loc)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'A': np.random.randint(low=1, high=N, size=N), 
                   'B': np.random.randint(low=1, high=N, size=N)
                  })

%%timeit -n 100
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']
df.sort_values(by='C')
```

naive: 100 loops, best of 3: 1.85 ms per loop

```
%%timeit -n 100
df.loc[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]
```

loc: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop

```
%%timeit -n 100
df.iloc[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]
```

iloc: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.02 ms per loop

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']

df1 = df.sort_values(by='C')
df2 = df.loc[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]
df3 = df.iloc[(df.A * df.B).sort_values().index]

print np.array_equal(df1.index, df2.index)
print np.array_equal(df2.index, df3.index)
```

testing results (comparing the entire index order) between all options:

True

True