# Order dataframe by row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
      C1  C2
John  4   3
Bob   5   7
Mary  6   5
Carl  5   6
James 4   3
```

How can I order my dataframe to have:

Carl, Mary, Bob, John, James

in an efficient way?

It is an arbitrary ordering and I might have the names stored in a variable *orderedNames*

Comment: read about `.sort_values()` method or `.sort_index()` depending on your goals...

Comment: What kind of ordering is that? Arbitrary? If so, do you have them in a list or a similar collection?

Comment: yes, please refer to the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***define your ordering***

```
arbitrary_ordering = ['Carl', 'Mary', 'Bob', 'John', 'James']
```

***option 1***
*`loc`*

```
df.loc[arbitrary_ordering]
```

***option 2***
*`reindex`*

```
df.reindex(arbitrary_ordering)
```

***option 3***
*`reindex_axis`*

```
df.reindex_axis(arbitrary_ordering)
```

All yield

```
       C1  C2
Carl    5   6
Mary    6   5
Bob     5   7
John    4   3
James   4   3
```

---

***alternative 1***

```
df.iloc[df.index.to_series().map(arbitrary_ordering.index)]
```

***alternative 2***
*`pd.Categorical`*

```
df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index, categories=arbitrary_ordering)
df.sort_index()
```

---

***Time Test***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can order them arbirtrarly using [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (suppose your data are in `df`)

```
df.loc[['Carl', 'Mary', 'Bob', 'John', 'James'], :]
```

However, if you want to order them by subset of columns use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
df.sort_values(by='C1')
```

Or even more advanced would be sorting by custom *key function*. See this question: [pandas sort lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525928/pandas-sort-lambda-function)