# Pythonic way to put specified value at last position when sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

For series `pd.Series(['d', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])`, how to sort it so that:

- `a` is the last item of the series
- all other items are ascending

So desired outcome will be: `pd.Series(['b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a'])`

Thanks

Comment: you can write your own compare function

Comment: so in general you want the minimum element to always appear last? but everything else is ascending?

Comment: @SaherAhwal not minimum element, but some specified item

Comment: @ZangMingJie can self-defined compare function be used in pandas sort_values function?

Comment: @StanFish Could you not just remove the specified element, sort the rest of the series, then add the specified element at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525928/pandas-sort-lambda-function please use search

Comment: @RoadRunner data set is kinda large, trying not to append / remove records or columns when doing sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort in two steps:

```
s = pd.Series(['d', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])

s.sort_values().pipe(lambda x: x.iloc[x.eq('a').values.argsort(kind='mergesort')])
# use mergesort to make sure the sorting is stable so the second sort doesn't change 
# the first sorting order when values are a and not a separately

#1    b
#3    b
#4    c
#0    d
#6    d
#2    a
#5    a
#dtype: object
```

---

Or create a dummpy data frame with an extra column indicating whether the values are equal to `a`, then sort by the two columns:

```
pd.concat([s.rename('s'), s.eq('a').rename('a')], axis=1).sort_values(['a', 's']).s

#1    b
#3    b
#4    c
#0    d
#6    d
#2    a
#5    a
#Name: s, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. How to apply mergesort to DataFrame pls? if say the series mentioned above is just one of the columns in the DataFrame

Comment: You should be able to apply the `kind='mergesort'` to `.sort_values` method as well. Something like `sort_values(['s'], kind='mergesort')`? But also notice *this option (kind) is only applied when sorting on a single column or label.* So if you sort by multiple columns, you can't choose the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can form the sorted series by sorting the values that aren't 'a' and then appending all the 'a' values.

```
sorted_series = ser[ser != 'a'].append(ser[ser == 'a'])
```