# Sort_values in pandas taking into account values from several columns' at once vs going sequentially through a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

When using `pd.DataFrame.sort_values(axis=0)` on multiple columns in Pandas 1.1.5 it is necessary to supply a list of column names for the 'by=' parameter. Let's call that list `X`. The default is such that pandas sorts by `X[0]`, then by `X[1]` and so on. This leads to interesting behaviour, see below:

sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.831, 1.0], [1.0, 0.984]], columns=[0, 1], dtype=np.float64)
```

let's sort using the default column order:

```
df.sort_values(by=[0, 1], ascending=[False, False]) 
       0      1
1  1.000  0.984
0  0.831  1.000
```

if we change column order in 'by' the result is:

```
df.sort_values(by=[1, 0], ascending=[False, False])
       0      1
0  0.831  1.000
1  1.000  0.984
```

Q: is it possible to perform sorting taking into account column values in several columns at once. Such that we get the first result regardless of column order. Of course, it is possible to create some summary column, which aggregates over all columns, and use it for sorting. But are there any other alternatives?

Comment: How about using `loc` as shown in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784801/3679377. You could as well use a lambda function as an input the the `key` arg.

Comment: Well what do you want to use to sort?

Comment: @najeem I am doing something similar, but I was hoping there is a better way, since I have a pretty large dataframe and creating an extra column feels superfluous